# How to track query execution time in N1QL of couchbase server?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Is there any easy way to get query time in couchbase server's N1QL like .explain() in mongodb?

I have a query like `SELECT c.name,  c.description  from customer c` and I would like to trace the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `N1QL`, responses are JSON and include metadata. the `metrics` field contains statistics, including the time taken to execute the query (so notably `elapsedTime` and `executionTime`).

in the `2.2.0 developer preview` of the Java SDK, you can access these metrics as a `QueryMetrics` object using the `info()` method on the `QueryResult`.

Comment: In addition to what Simon said, we are looking into adding trace times for high-level phases, e.g. parse, sort. This is not straightforward in N1QL, because some of the phases are parallelized, even for a single query.